# Rails active record's 'where' method anomaly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I tried the following statement in the rails console:

```
SomeModel.where(["active = ? and price = ? and status_date <= ?", true , nil , Date.parse('20161101')]).size
```

This gave me `>> 0`

Then I modified the above statement to this:

```
SomeModel.where([ "active = ? and status_date <= ?", true , Date.parse('20161101') ]).where(price: nil).size
```

This gave me `>> 533`

Can someone explain why is this happening? Why aren't these two statements giving the same output?

Specs: Rails 5.0.0, Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a comparison with `NULL` the query needs to be `price IS NULL` instead of `price = NULL`

Using `where(price: nil)` will generate the correct SQL for you whereas `price = ?` with a parameter value of `nil` will not match any records.

Comment: Thanks. So, is there a way to make the query look like the first statement?

Comment: If you're always comparing with `NULL` then you can write the condition inline and drop the parameter - `where(["active = ? and price IS NULL`... if you sometimes have a value for price and sometimes have `NULL` then using the second style of querying takes care of generating the different queries for you and so is a better choice.